# Can't import the named export 'EmptyPcset' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic-react

I'm working with a react ionic project, after installing the node modules and trying to run the project, the below issue is displayed:

"./node_modules/@tonaljs/scale-type/dist/index.mjs
Can't import the named export 'EmptyPcset' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)"

My packages version:

- tonaljs/tonal:  4.6.5
- react-scripts:  4.0.2
- react:  17.0.2
- typescript: 4.1.3
- ionic/react:  6.0.1
- Ionic CLI       : 6.20.3
- Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 6.6.3
- cordova-res : 0.15.4
- native-run  : 1.7.2
- NodeJS : v14.18.1
- npm    : 6.14.15
- OS       : Linux 5.19

I tried to update the tonaljs/tonal, and/or react-scripts to the newer versions with no luck. There is a solution that stated that we should update the webpack configuration but I couldn't find the file in react ionic and I didn't get it how to update the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic React uses Create React App (CRA) to build the app.

With Create React App, normally you cannot edit the configuration-- prohibiting configuration edits is how CRA ensures it is easy to upgrade.

To modify the webpack config, you have two options:

- [Eject from CRA.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject)
- Add another package like [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired).